# How to disable see-through mesh

Tags: mesh, transparency, edit-mode

I have a mesh wich currently looks like this on edit mode:

[image]

Even though I haven't activated the Z key to enter wireframe mode, I can see the edges behind the mesh. This is really annoying since I keep accidentally selecting the vertices at the back.

How can I disable this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to check the "Limit Selection To Visible" button

[image]

in the toolbar in Edit mode. This will hide the back edges from view.

[image]