# Viewport Wireframe Backface Culling

Tags: 3d-view, wireframe

In viewport is it possible to cull backfaces of wireframes? (To make wireframes disappear while looking through the back side of the polygons.)

It is confusing to work with overlaping wireframes. So far I could only find the solution to hide and show the oposite side of the object while constructing the topology which is not so productive.
[image]

Thanks for your reply Cegaton. That reduces the confusion a lot. I can't beleive I missed it. Though I still need to ask if I can hide the object's frontal wireframe faces behind the sculpted arm as seen below. It would help to see the details on the object more clear while deciding to add geometry.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Edit Mode Transparent Objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34245/edit-mode-transparent-objects) and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43168/how-to-select-polygons-facing-camera-instead-of-polygons-located-in-the-opposite/43175#43175 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51503/how-to-disable-see-through-mesh/51504#51504

Comment: Not sure what is the end goal to "hide frontal wireframe faces behind sculpted arm" but maybe try [Hidden Wire](https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/editors/3dview/properties/shading.html#shading-panel) which can help for retopology (but may not). Also please ask only one question per post to keep the questions/answers searchable. You can ask new one if needed.

Comment: I disagree with the closure of this question. This is in no way a duplicate of "Edit Mode Transparent Objects". X-ray and backface culling are two very different things. I would have an answer to give including multiple solutions that were not provided by the other answer. Can someone please re-open it?

Answer (score 2):

Use the "Limit selection to visible" option.

[image]

[image]

From the [Manual:](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/selecting/introduction.html?highlight=limit%20selection%20visible#limit-selection-to-visible)

> **Limit Selection to Visible**
>
> If you are in solid, shaded, or textured viewport shading mode (not bounding box or wireframe), you will have a fourth button in the header that looks like a cube, just right of the select mode ones.
>
> When enabled, this limits your ability to view and select vertices occluded by the objects geometry (as if the object was solid). This is done by the viewport with depth buffer clipping.